# Access results of intervals.lme as a dataframe + r + lme

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, confidence-interval, nlme

I am using a linear mixed effects model to determine the relationship between 2 variables over time, model -

```
data(mtcars)

# linear mixed effects model
mlme <- lme(mpg ~ wt, random = ~ 1|cyl, data = mtcars)
```

I then access the confidence intervals using -

```
conf <- intervals(mlme, level = 0.95, which = 'fixed')
conf
```

Returning the results -

```
Approximate 95% confidence intervals

 Fixed effects:
               lower      est.    upper
(Intercept) 7.431921 18.416639 29.40136
DairyTotal  2.001397  6.716849 11.43230
```

I want to access the values of the lower and upper limits so I can use them as variables but can't find a method to do so. If you want to access the coefficients for example you can use `coef(summary(mlme))` and convert it to a dataframe.

I tried converting the result to a dataframe using `data.frame(coef)` but get the error:

```
> data.frame(conf)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"intervals.lme"’ to a data.frame
```

Can anyone recommend a method to access variables that are returned in this format?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: That fair, I was hoping it was just something procedural as R returns a lot of variables are returned in this format... I will make it reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with the mtcars dataset how we could access the lower and upper ci as variables:

```
library(nlme)

data(mtcars)

# linear mixed effects model
mlme <- lme(mpg ~ wt, random = ~ 1|cyl, data = mtcars)

# Confidence intervals
conf <- intervals(mlme, level = 0.95, which = 'fixed')

# Lower and upper confidence intervals as variables
lower <- conf$fixed["(Intercept)", "lower"]
upper <- conf$fixed["(Intercept)", "upper"]

[1] 25.7204
[1] 37.32919
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'll use sample datasets to create my example in future.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility would be to use `broom.mixed::tidy()`.  Using @TarJae's example:

```r
broom.mixed::tidy(mlme, conf.int = TRUE, effects = "fixed") |> 
     dplyr::select(term, estimate, conf.low, conf.high)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  term        estimate conf.low conf.high
  <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 (Intercept)    31.5     25.7      37.3 
2 wt             -3.52    -4.99     -2.04
```